# Add contact to "Only Phone"

Tags: contacts, settings, sync, privacy, xiaomi

I can't save contacts to "Only Phone" as long as I'm logged into Xiaomi account. I have to log off to be able to (If not, I'm forced to sync new contacts either with Google account or Xiaomi's).

This shouldn't be like this since I've specified in the settings that I don't want Xiaomi to sync anything but the service to locate my phone in case I loose it.

The only way to get ride of this "forced sync" is to log off permanently of Xiaomi account that is what I am doing now because I don't like this behaviour.

Anyone knows how to achieve it without having to log off of Xiaomi account?

EDIT: Using Redmi Note 4, Android 7